Why do Fixest Feols and Lfe Felm output different event study results?
I am running a handful of event studies in R. I am employing both the felm function from the lfe package and the feols function from the fixest package. I am running what I thought were identical event studies, but the two functions output different event study results. I do not understand why. If anybody could help me determine why the two event study codes produce different results that would be greatly appreciated.
The following are my codes for the lfe and fixest packages and their outputs, respectively:
 #import packages
library(haven)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lfe)
library(fixest)

#import data
data = setDT(read_dta("https://github.com/w-tres-mil/honorsthesis/raw/main/balanced_panel.dta"))

#create variables
data[,percentblack:=black/totenroll][,percentpoor:=free_reduced/totenroll][,percentsped:=sped_num/totenroll][,percentell:=ell_num/totenroll]

#clean variables
data[,schoolid:=as.numeric(schoolid)][,corpid:=as.numeric(corpid)][,year:=as.numeric(year)]

#create leads and lags
data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    cba_lead1 = case_when(time_til_cba == -1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead2 = case_when(time_til_cba == -2 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead3 = case_when(time_til_cba == -3 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead4 = case_when(time_til_cba == -4 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead5 = case_when(time_til_cba == -5 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead6 = case_when(time_til_cba == -6 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead7 = case_when(time_til_cba == -7 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead8 = case_when(time_til_cba == -8 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead9 = case_when(time_til_cba == -9 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead10 = case_when(time_til_cba == -10 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead11 = case_when(time_til_cba == -11 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead12 = case_when(time_til_cba == -12 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead13 = case_when(time_til_cba == -13 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lead14 = case_when(time_til_cba == -14 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    
    cba_lag0 = case_when(time_til_cba == 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lag1 = case_when(time_til_cba == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lag2 = case_when(time_til_cba == 2 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lag3 = case_when(time_til_cba == 3 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lag4 = case_when(time_til_cba == 4 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lag5 = case_when(time_til_cba == 5 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    cba_lag6 = case_when(time_til_cba == 6 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)
  )

data <- data %>%
  mutate(
    rtw_lead1 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead2 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -2 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead3 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -3 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead4 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -4 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead5 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -5 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead6 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -6 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead7 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -7 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead8 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -8 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead9 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -9 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead10 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -10 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead11 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -11 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead12 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -12 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead13 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -13 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lead14 = case_when(time_til_rtw == -14 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    
    rtw_lag0 = case_when(time_til_rtw == 0 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lag1 = case_when(time_til_rtw == 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lag2 = case_when(time_til_rtw == 2 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lag3 = case_when(time_til_rtw == 3 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lag4 = case_when(time_til_rtw == 4 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
    rtw_lag5 = case_when(time_til_rtw == 5 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0),
  )

#create function for plot
saveevent = function(f){
  ggsave(
    filename = f,
    plot = last_plot(),
    path = "/Users/tracemiller/Documents/thesis/visuals/event studies/twfe",
    scale = 1,
    width = 7,
    height = 5,
    units = "in",
    device = "pdf"
  )
}

#split data
cba = data[treatedrtw==0]
rtw = data[treatedcba==1|treatcba==0]
both = data[cba_treatdate==rtw_treatdate]

#lfe felm

felm_istepela_cba_nc = as.formula(
  paste("istepelanorm ~ + ",
        paste(
          paste(paste("cba_lead", 2:10, sep = ""), collapse = " + "),
          paste(paste("cba_lag", 0:6, sep = ""), collapse = " + "),sep = " + "),
        "| year + corpid + schoolid | 0 | corpid"
  ),
)

felm_istepela_cba_nc <- felm(felm_istepela_cba_nc, data = cba)
summary(felm_istepela_cba_nc)

plot_order <- c("cba_lead10", "cba_lead9", "cba_lead8", "cba_lead7", 
                "cba_lead6", "cba_lead5", "cba_lead4", "cba_lead3", 
                "cba_lead2", "cba_lag0", "cba_lag1", 
                "cba_lag2", "cba_lag3", "cba_lag4", "cba_lag5","cba_lag6")


leadslags_plot <- tibble(
  sd = c(felm_istepela_cba_nc$cse[plot_order],0),
  mean = c(coef(felm_istepela_cba_nc)[plot_order],0),
  label = c(-10,-9,-8,-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2,0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,-1)
)

leadslags_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = label, y = mean,
             ymin = mean-1.96*sd, 
             ymax = mean+1.96*sd)) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Years wrt SB575 (TWFE split)") +
  ylab("ISTEP ELA Norm") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -1,
             linetype = "dashed")


#fixest feols

feols_istepela_cba_nc = feols(istepelanorm ~ i(time_til_cba,treatcba,ref=-1) | 
                                corpid + schoolid + year,
                              cluster = ~corpid,
                              data = cba)

iplot(feols_istepela_cba_nc)

Lfe Felm output
Fixest Feols output
I am very confused, because the lfe felm code is a traditional code for running and plotting event studies, but fixest feols has been dubbed the gold standard for event study running and plotting. I do not understand why the results are different. I assumed that it was because of the interaction term in the fixest feols function, so ran and plotted a fixest feols regression on leads and lags, which produced an output identical to that of the lfe felm regression:
#fixest feols with leads and lags

feols_istepela_cba = feols(istepelanorm ~ cba_lead10+cba_lead9+cba_lead8+cba_lead7+cba_lead6+cba_lead5+cba_lead4+cba_lead3+cba_lead2
                           + cba_lag0+cba_lag1+cba_lag2+cba_lag3+cba_lag4+cba_lag5+cba_lag6| 
                                corpid + schoolid + year,
                              cluster = ~corpid,
                              data = cba)

coefplot(feols_istepela_cba)


Fixest Feols with leads and lags
My next thought is that it is perhaps the absence of the non-treated units in the fixest feols regression (cancelled out by the binary "treatcba" term) or the presence of the non-treated units in the lfe felm regression (the non-treated units are treated after the end of the panel data set, so they are coded as non-treated, but they have leads and lags for time to treatment). So I set the non-treated units as treated for the fixest feols regression (I code the binary "cba_treat" term as 1 for all untis) and drop the non-treated units for the lfe felm regression. However, the outputs are even more different:
#fixest feols for treat and nontreat

cba = cba[!is.na(cba_treatdate),treatcba:=1]

feols_istepela_cba_nc1 = feols(istepelanorm ~ i(time_til_cba,treatcba,ref=-1) | 
                                corpid + schoolid + year,
                              cluster = ~corpid,
                              data = cba)

iplot(feols_istepela_cba_nc1)

#lfe felm for treat but not nontreat

cba = cba[cba_treatdate<2018]

felm_istepela_cba_nc1 = as.formula(
  paste("istepelanorm ~ + ",
        paste(
          paste(paste("cba_lead", 2:10, sep = ""), collapse = " + "),
          paste(paste("cba_lag", 0:6, sep = ""), collapse = " + "),sep = " + "),
        "| year + corpid + schoolid | 0 | corpid"
  ),
)

felm_istepela_cba_nc1 <- felm(felm_istepela_cba_nc1, data = cba)
summary(felm_istepela_cba_nc1)

plot_order <- c("cba_lead10", "cba_lead9", "cba_lead8", "cba_lead7", 
                "cba_lead6", "cba_lead5", "cba_lead4", "cba_lead3", 
                "cba_lead2", "cba_lag0", "cba_lag1", 
                "cba_lag2", "cba_lag3", "cba_lag4", "cba_lag5","cba_lag6")


leadslags_plot <- tibble(
  sd = c(felm_istepela_cba_nc1$cse[plot_order],0),
  mean = c(coef(felm_istepela_cba_nc1)[plot_order],0),
  label = c(-10,-9,-8,-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2,0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,-1)
)

leadslags_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = label, y = mean,
             ymin = mean-1.96*sd, 
             ymax = mean+1.96*sd)) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("Years wrt SB575 (TWFE split)") +
  ylab("ISTEP ELA Norm") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -1,
             linetype = "dashed")

Fixest feols with all units coded treated
Lfe felm with non-treated units dropped
All in all, I fail to understand what would cause this difference in results. Perhaps I am missing something about how the interaction term in the fixest feols regression works. If anybody has any advice or wisdom, that would be greatly appreciated.

I believe I have found the answer: fixest feols drops leads and lags in order to stop multicollinearity. Obviously lfe felm can't drop leads and lags. When I rewrite the lfe felm regression and run it with the same combination of leads and lags that fixiest feols employs automatically, the outputs are identical:
istepela_sctfe_nocontrols = feols(istepelanorm ~i(time_til_cba,treatcba,ref=-1) + i(time_til_rtw,treatrtw,ref=-1)|
                                   schoolid + year + corpid,
                                 cluster = ~corpid,
                                 data = data)

istepela_sctfe_nocontrols_leadslags = feols(istepelanorm ~ cba_lead11+cba_lead10+cba_lead9+cba_lead8+cba_lead7+cba_lead6+cba_lead5+cba_lead4+cba_lead3+cba_lead2+
                                              cba_lag0+cba_lag1+cba_lag2+cba_lag3+cba_lag4+cba_lag5+rtw_lead10+
                                              rtw_lead9+rtw_lead8+rtw_lead7+rtw_lead6+rtw_lead5+rtw_lead4+rtw_lead3+rtw_lead2+
                                              rtw_lag0+rtw_lag1+rtw_lag2+rtw_lag3+rtw_lag4|
                                    schoolid + year +corpid ,
                                  cluster = ~corpid,
                                  data = data)

coefplot(list(istepela_sctfe_nocontrols,istepela_sctfe_nocontrols_leadslags))

left: fixest feols output; right: lfe felm output

What would be the correct way to do it then? I found the same issue when replicating the event study model here (Replicating Cheng and Hoekstra (2013), sort of, 'event_study_reg' in castle_2.R) using fixest::feols, and found exactly this issue (different results when using i(time_until_treatment) but same ones when using lead/lag dummies).
